# what happen with my schema mysql? (perfomance slow)

Tags: mysql

i have a table like this

```
id  int(10) unsigned    
order_match_id  int(11)         
users_star_member_id    int(11)         
users_id    int(11)         
createdAt   datetime                
createdBy   int(11)             
expiredAt   datetime            
updatedAt   datetime        
updatedBy   int(11)         
total_price_star_member decimal(10,2)           
discount_price_star_member  decimal(10,2)
```

with total only 84824 rows inside of that table

```
SELECT *,month(osm.createdAt) as createMonth, year(osm.createdAt) as createYear 
FROM order_star_member osm
where createdAt=(select MIN(createdAt) from order_star_member b 
                  where b.users_id=osm.users_id
                 )
AND osm.createdAt >= '2019-12-01';
```

why it took it so long and never executed (just loading) and i have to canceled it because it never be done. is there anyway to make this perfomance better?

Comment: Stick an index on (users_id,created_at)

Comment: And never use evil `SELECT *`

Comment: your first answers is the solution, should i deleted this question or what sir? @Strawberry

Comment: Either delete, or answer and accept (when time allows). Up to you.

Comment: can you please just answer and i will accept your answer